# CSS top img not directly on top of back img when hovering over the button

Tags: html, css

I have a button which I have put two icons, one grey and one blue. I have hidden the blue image by add `display: none;` and when I hover over the button I change the css to `display: block;`. The blue image shows but is not directly over the grey image.

```css
.page-btn-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0 none !important;
}

.page-btn-icon .icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.page-btn-icon .img-top {
  display: none;
}

.page-btn-icon:hover .img-top {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="page-btn-icon">
  <!--<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/icons/filter_g.png' %}">
  <img class="icon img-top" src="{% static 'img/icons/filter_b.png' %}">-->
  <img class="icon" src="https://dummyimage.com/16x16/fff/aaa">
  <img class="icon img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/16x16/aaa/fff">
</button>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `display: grid;` and `place-items:center;` for the parent element?

Maybe also try changing just the `opacity` instead of the `display` values to keep things consistent.

Comment: @Johannes ah sorry, I was trying both and neither worked.

Comment: You aren't adding any CSS that's hiding the gray icon - or even any positioning that would put the blue icon above the current icon.

Comment: Updated question with snippet showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes the problem by making it so the first image is `display:none` when hovered, and the second image is changed from `display:none` to `display:inline-block`.

```css
.page-btn-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0 none !important;
}

.page-btn-icon .icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.page-btn-icon .img-top,
.page-btn-icon:hover .icon {
  display: none;
}

.page-btn-icon:hover .img-top {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="page-btn-icon">
  <img class="icon" src="https://dummyimage.com/16x16/fff/aaa">
  <img class="icon img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/16x16/aaa/fff">
</button>
```

I would get rid of the two images, and just flip the background image of the button based on the hover state.  Much cleaner.

```css
.page-btn-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0 none !important;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/16x16/fff/aaa');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.page-btn-icon:hover {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/16x16/aaa/fff');
}
```

```html
<button class="page-btn-icon">
</button>
```